# how to fit a curve in the form of A = (L^x)(D^y) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, regression, curve-fitting

i have some response data as vector A where the variables are L and D.

I just want to find the coefficients for L and D which will fit my data in the form mentioned in the title.

I want to fit a curved line, and not a surface.

I feel it should be fairly simple, but reading a few old answers also didn't help my case.

Is there some easy way to do this?

In case u want to see the data, here it is:

```
A = [0 0.06 0.12 0.44 0.56 0.94 1 1 0 0.04 0.58 0.74 0.86 1 1]

L = [100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 43.7 49.7 56 61.5 65 77 93.8]

D = [11.3 10.1 8.9 8.5 8.1 7.7 6.5 5.3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
```

Thanks a lot.

More info:

I wrote the above equation as `logA = xlogL + ylogD`, and tried to use

```
X = [ones(size(logL)) logL logD];

b = regress(logA,X);
```

but Matlab didn't return any coefficients, it just gave `b = NaN NaN NaN`

Comment: you have `A=0` and `log(0)=-inf` is kind of a problematic...

Comment: ya, instead of 0 i can use a very small number close to zero, or just ignore that particular data point altogether. in cftool, matlab just ignores that log(0).

Comment: you might want to substitute all zeros with `realmin`: `realmin` is the smallest, positive, double precision floating point number that your machine is able to generate (`2.2251e-308`). In `A` just do something like `A(A==0)=realmin` and check if the problem persists.

Comment: You are about to fit function defined as `A=f(x,y)`, which IS a surface. If you want to fit curve You need to define some function that binds `x` to `y` to get `(x,y,z)=f(t)` form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jos from  mathworks forum gave me the correct answer. Here it is:

> nlm = fitnlm([L(:) D(:)], A, 'y~(x1^b1)*(x2^b2)', [0 0])

In case you dont have fitnlm, NonLinearModel.fit will also do. In fact, I used the latter.

Hope this helps someone.